# Can't putExtra in Intent in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm trying to do a `putExtra` in a ViewModel but I get this error:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

This is my code:

```
   val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
   intent.action = MyService.ACTION_ONE
   intent.putExtra("data", mydata)
   ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent)
```

Why I can't do `putExtra`?

Comment: Apparently, `mydata` is not of a data type than can go into an `Intent` extra. What is `mydata`?

Comment: mydata is LiveData<Int>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass `LiveData<Int>` in an `Intent` extra. You could pass the current `Int` value (`mydata.value`) as an `Intent` extra, if you wanted.